# the pyqt5 timer event not working in a qthread?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtimer

I need to calculate a number in a thread and then to process the data, but the timer in a thread not working.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QObject, QThread, pyqtSlot, QTimer
import sys, time

class Worker(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.i = 0
        self.startTimer(100)

    def timerEvent(self, QTimerEvent):
        self.i += 2

    @pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        while True:
            print(self.i)
            time.sleep(1)

class Demo(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.worker = Worker()
        self.thread = QThread()
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.run)
        self.thread.start()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
demo = Demo()
demo.show()
app.exec()
```

The teminal show 0 always, can anyone help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signals and events need an event loop to work. When you use a `QThread` you create that event loop but when using `time.sleep()` you are blocking it preventing `timerEvent()` method from being invoked. So the solution is to replace `time.sleep()` with another option (QEventLoop + QTimer) that does not block it.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class Worker(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.i = 0
        self.m_id = self.startTimer(100)

    def timerEvent(self, event):
        if self.m_id == event.timerId():
            self.i += 2
        super().timerEvent(event)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        while True:
            print(self.i)
            loop = QtCore.QEventLoop()
            QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(1000, loop.quit)
            loop.exec()


class Demo(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        thread = QtCore.QThread(self)
        self.worker = Worker()
        self.worker.moveToThread(thread)
        thread.started.connect(self.worker.run)
        thread.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    demo = Demo()
    demo.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: i had try the solution you give, it works fine.